# Apache proxy HTTP CONNECT method handshake failure between Apache server and destination server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, http, tunneling

Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y

I'm trying to get the HTTP CONNECT method working with Apache. I'm testing it with two different destination servers. It works fine with one server, but fails with the other. Below is the Wireshark trace for the connection between the Apache server and the destination server where it fails. It looks like the Apache server sends an Alert before it gives the destination server a chance to send the Server Hello. Why is this happening?

Apache -> Destination   TCP 57070 > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Destination -> Apache   TCP https > 57070 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4380 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1

Apache -> Destination   TCP 57070 > https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131328 Len=0

Apache -> Destination   SSLv3   Client Hello

Apache -> Destination   SSLv3   Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)

Apache -> Destination   TCP 57070 > https [FIN, ACK] Seq=80 Ack=1 Win=131328 Len=0

Destination -> Apache   SSLv3   Server Hello

Apache -> Destination   TCP 57070 > https [RST, ACK] Seq=81 Ack=1461 Win=0 Len=0

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this wasn't working was because Apache is sending the response to the CONNECT request as two separate packets:

Packet 1: HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established

Packet 2: Proxy-agent: Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y

I was breaking from the socket read loop on "200 Connection" and Packet 2 was being used as the Server Hello since it was the next packet in the queue.